# Не запускаются потоки параллельно

Tags: python, многопоточность

```
thread_count=2
def worker(th):
    func.putlog("--стартовал поток "+str(th));
    i=0
    while i<thread_count:
     func.putlog("--поток "+str(th)+", шаг "+str(i))
     time.sleep(1)
     i=i+1
def main():
    func.putlog("-скрипт стартовал!");    
    #запускаем потоки
    for _ in xrange(thread_count):
      thread_ = threading.Thread(target=worker(_))
      thread_.start()

    #ждем пока потоки завершатся    
    while threading.active_count() >1:
     time.sleep(1)
    func.putlog("-скрипт закончил работу!");     
main();
```

Выводит последовательно:

```
    -скрипт стартовал!
    --стартовал поток 0
    --поток 0, шаг 0
    --поток 0, шаг 1
    --стартовал поток 1
    --поток 1, шаг 0
    --поток 1, шаг 1
    -скрипт закончил работу!
```

Хотя по идее должно же выполнятся всё параллельно?

Comment: Поправьте отступы в циклах.

Answer (score 4):

Ты вызываешь функцию `worker` при инициализации потока, в строке `thread_ = threading.Thread(target=worker(_))` и передаёшь в конструктор потока её выход - None. Т. е. потоки вовсе не запускаются

Comment: `thread_ = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(_,))`

Comment: Пасиб, заработало